# Do Gym Badges make it easier to catch high level Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

When you earn a Gym Badge in Pokémon Scarlet and Violet the defeated leader mentions it will be easier to catch Pokémon up to a certain level.

I know Gym Badges make higher level Pokémon obey you, but does "easier to catch" mean badges also improve your catch rate for high level Pokémon?

[image: Katy giving first badge]
<sub>Screenshot from [Nintendo Unity - Pokémon Scarlet & Violet - All Gym Leader Battles (4:19)](https://youtu.be/dZjJOXCYRug?t=259)</sub>

Comment: [Possibly Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/394517/124566). Though the question was for a Gen8 game, the answer might still become be applicable; or at least a similar mechanic was implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do.
According to [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/scarletviolet/catchmechanics.shtml):

> When the Pokémon are above the level of your current badge level, the catch rate is calculated at 0.8 to the power of each badge you don't have.

I tried to make this clearer with some numbers:

| Missing badges | Multiplier |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0,8 |
| 2 | 0,64 |
| 3 | 0,512 |
| 4 | 0,4096 |
| 5 | 0,32768 |
| 6 | 0,262144 |
| 7 | 0,2097152 |
| 8 | 0,16777216 |